# Cloudflare redirect with set cached response

Tags: cloudflare

I have a URL (A) which responds with a cached resource and status code 304.

In Cloudflare, I've setup a forwarding URL page rule (temporary redirect) to forward A to the new URL (B). Unfortunately, this is not working. Is it possible that the 304 response is taking precedence?

Some additional notes:

- Cloudflare Browser Cache Expiration setting is set to "Respect Existing Headers"
- Cloudflare caching level is set to "Standard"
- URL A and B are both on the same subdomain and the HTTP proxy is turned on

Comment: I've managed to clear the resource from cache and resource is returning 200 every time. However the Redirect is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Set the HTTP Proxy on the DNS setting and be patient.